# What happens when someone with a mature clone is turned into a vampire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead

If someone casts [Clone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) on themselves and allows the clone to mature, then subsequently is turned into a Vampire, does the soul flee the now-vampiric undead body to activate the clone, leaving the vampire version of themselves out there? Or would the Clone merely act as an extra backup in case someone succeeds in destroying them as a vampire?

Comment: Is there a precedent for vampires without souls?

Comment: @BlakeSteel in a lot of various vampire lore, vampires are soulless... er... no human soul anyway.

Answer (score 13):

## You can't turn into a vampire without triggering an active *[Clone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone)* spell.

The reason for this is that, to turn into a vampire, you first have to die. Specifically, you can become a vampire (spawn) by being bitten by a true vampire and being buried in the ground. In the following night, you rise as a vampire spawn.

> **Bite (Bat or Vampire Form only)** [...] A humanoid slain in this way and then buried in the ground rises the following night as a vampire spawn under the vampire's control.

Therefore, to turn into a vampire, your clone *cannot be mature yet*. Otherwise, it will trigger once you die, preventing you from turning into a vampire spawn.

---

If the clone matures after you die from the vampire's bite, but before you resurrect as a vampire spawn, it won't trigger:

> At any time **after the clone matures**, if the original creature dies, its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul is free and willing to return.

---

If your clone matures after you rise as a vampire spawn, it most likely won't trigger either. This is for a number of reasons:

- The *Clone* spell only triggers "if the original creature dies". Whether or not you as the vampire spawn still count as "the original creature" is debateable, and therefore up to your DM.
- The *Clone* spell requires the soul to be "free and willing to return". You as a vampire spawn are under the control of the vampire who created you - whether this is just physical or if it also applies to your soul (rendering it not-free) is unclear, and therefore also up to your DM.

> At any time after the clone matures, if the **original creature** dies, its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the **soul is free and willing to return**.

Hence, it'll be up to your DM to decide whether or not a vampire spawn with a clone will resurrect as the clone upon death.

By the way: if you *Wish* for yourself to become a vampire, or if you permanently *True Polymorph* into a vampire (or any other creature for that matter), only the first issue applies, since you will then be a free-willed vampire (or vampire spawn, but I'm not sure why anyone would choose to be vampire spawn over being a true vampire).

Comment: So Clone becomes a 'Get out of Vampirism free' card. Not bad!

Comment: Where exactly does it say that the soul is still in the risen Vampire Spawn? It seems just as likely that your body dies, your soul activates your clone, AND your corpse arises as a Vampire Spawn. Is there anything in RAW that prevents that interpretation?

Comment: @MarkTO Well, there's the fact that "The original creature's physical remains, if they still exist, become inert and can't thereafter be restored to life" (Clone, PHB p. 222) And although undead creatures are not humanoids, they are a form of life. This can be confirmed by the fact that if a zombie is killed and then revivified, it [remains a zombie](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/709791324656902144) in spite of the fact that it "returns to life" (Revivify, PHB, p. 272).

Comment: _clone_ getting you out of vampirism free, if it's already primed, seems like a natural extension of _clone_ getting you out of ordinary death free, and with the other return-from-death spells (note in particular that _resurrection_ doesn't work if you have _already_ risen as an undead).

Comment: _True Polymorph_ specifies that "You transform the creature into a different creature." Contrasted with the fact that _Polymorph_ says "transforms a creature with at least 1 hit point that you can see within range into a new form", I think the implication is you are not the original creature. Maybe a carefully worded _Wish_ could work around that still, however.

Comment: @SnoringFrog i have to disagree. You are certainly, yourself "a creature with at least 1 HP, within range, that you can see"

Comment: @user3801839 That doesn't contradict anything I said. In each case, you are _a_ creature. The issue is whether you are _the original_ creature (from _Clone_'s perspective). I pointed out the wording difference between _Polymorph_ and _True Polymorph_ as evidence that the latter causes you to no longer be the original creature, prevent _Clone_ from activating (with a permanent TP, at least; non-permanent would revert to the original creature at 0hp, so you'd be the original creature and could trigger _Clone_. Still not entirely cut and dry, but that's my reading of it.